# Dvorak-QWERTY keyboard does not properly switch between keyboards when I press Command button on Safari

Tags: safari, macos, shortcut

Original question: What is the new shortcut to get to select the address line on Safari?

I always used to use the Command+L to select/highlight the URL and go to another website. This changed in macOS Sierra. Now when I press those buttons, it will create a new window.

Is there a new shortcut to select the address?

–––

Edit:

Ok, I think I found the issue: the standard keyboard I work on is Dvorak - QWERTY.
It means the keys are in the Dvorak layout when I type normally, and they become QWERTY when I press the command button. I use this because many shortcuts are in favour of the QWERTY Layout.

I confirmed on another keyboard that selecting the address bar is still indeed Command+L. The reason Safari would open a new window instead is because the "L" button in QWERTY is "N" in Dvorak layout. Command+N is open a new window! It would mean that in macOS Sierra, pressing the command button does not always turn the layout in QWERTY, and sometimes it inputs the key value in Dvorak even if I press down the command button... How do I fix this issue?

Comment: ⌘L in Safari under macOS Sierra is Open Location..., just like in OS X El Capitan and other versions of OS X. It still highlights the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Check Safari menu that you have the same picture as below.
If anything is different then you need to check System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts to see if you have any other keys assigned to these menu items.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have exactly what you have there, and I did not make any modifications or added shortcuts. The reason seems to be the glitch in the keyboard I use that switches the layout depending on whether I am pressing down the command key or not. I updated the original question. Thank you.